# Google Maps API Display icon along route at a specific distance from start

Tags: google-maps-api-3, tags

I want to display virtual progress on a Google map.
I want to display a map with a route and on that route I want to display an icon at some distance (that will be computed based on data) from the start. That distance could change from moment to moment or day to day depending on the data related to the progress along the virtual route.
For instance on a route from LA to NY, one day I may want to display an icon at 772 miles from the start. The distance along the route can be in units or as a percentage.
I have seen the google.maps.IconSequence object, but can't see how to use that with DirectionsService.

Comment: I suppose you could keep an array variable matching all the segments of your polyline, and use a distance measuring function to determine how long each segment is. Then, given a percentage, figure out which segment should be marked.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of "mile marker/kilometer marker" examples and an animated marker:

- [every 2 km](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html)
- [2 markers at specific distances along a route](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)
- [An animated marker along a route](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html)