# Find destination based on distance google map api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a website that use google map api. Now I have latitude and longitude of the start point. I also know the route of the journey, and the distance. How can I find the latitude and logitude of the end point?

Comment: Well if you know the route you should have the end location of it, shouldn't you?

Comment: I mean If I have a route that is 100 kilometer length (I know the start point and the end point). Now I want to find the location of a point that has distance 2 kilometer from start point. Sorry if my question is so confusing, my english isn't so good !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Display icon along route at a specific distance from start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152382/google-maps-api-display-icon-along-route-at-a-specific-distance-from-start)

Comment: related question: [Calculate the geo position at given time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562799/calculate-the-geo-position-at-given-time)

Comment: I used this one: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html . Thanks so much !!!